# Calling web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount throws error

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, web3js, go-ethereum

I am on `web3 1.0.0-beta.27`, and I ran a private blockchain as:
    geth --identity "node" --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --datadir path/to/data --networkid 123 --ws --wsport 8546 --wsorigins "*" console

Then in a `app.ts` file I have:

```
import * as Web3 from 'web3';

var web3   = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546'));

web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
    var sender = accounts[0];
    web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(sender, 'password');
});
```

But I get error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Returned error: The method personal_newAccount does not exist/is not available
```

Searching online for this issue, I should have started the `geth` process with `--rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3"`, however adding this flag does not help, even though `rpc` is just a kind of `ipc` correct?

Furthermore, on the geth console I am able to unlock the account with

```
personal.unlockAccount(sender, 'password')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added `personal` to `rpcapi`, but are connecting through WS. You need to add it to `wsapi`.

> rpc is just a kind of ipc correct?

The 3 connection protocols are IPC-RPC, JSON-RPC, and WS-RPC. The `rpc*` configuration parameters are for JSON-RPC (over HTTP), not IPC/WS.